# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, express, fetch

Can anyone tell me why this code will work perfectly in an HTML page when accessing the data from my hard drive but when I add it to express and node I get a

> **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

with perfectly formatted code.  I know I tested it with a formatter and I even manually created a json object.  Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="description" content="">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Untitled</title>
        </head>
        <body>

    <div id="output"></div>

          <button id="getProperty">Get Property</button>

          <script>
            document.getElementById('getProperty').addEventListener('click', getProperty);


            function getProperty() {
                fetch('2016-regular.json')
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    let output = '<h2>Property</h2>';
                    console.log(data);
                    data.propertystandings.propertystandingsentry.forEach(function(propertyEntry){
                        output += `
                            <ul>
                                <li>id: ${propertyEntry.property.ID}</li>
                                <li>city: ${propertyEntry.property.City}</li>
                                <li>prop name: ${propertyEntry.property.Name}</li>
                                <li>prop name: ${propertyEntry.rank}</li>
                            </ul>
                        `;
                    });
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = output;
                })
            }
          </script>

        </body>
    </html>
</html>
</html>
But then this code in express causes the error- same exact file that worked perfectly before ran thru express now causes this error: 
**"index.ejs"**

    <div id="output"></div>

          <button id="getProperty">Get Property</button>

    <script>

            document.getElementById('getProperty').addEventListener('click', getProperty);


            function getProperty() {
                /*fetch('sample.txt')
                .then(function(res) {
                    return res.text();
                })
                .then(function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                });*/
                fetch("2016-regular.json")
                .then((res) => res.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    console.log(data);//**won't even read the data without that error**
                });
            }
    </script>


**express code**
var express = require('express');
//var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(cors());

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.render('index.ejs');
});

app.listen(8000, function() {
    console.log('running on 8000');
});
```

any ideas why this works fine in plain html when accessing a folder or if I manually create and save the file on my hard drive but once I put it in express or try to access the API the data came from (the final goal) I get the error **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

Comment: We probably don't need that giant wall of code, and rather just the JSON itself

Comment: I agree but there is nothing I can do to the way it is formatted because it is coming from an api.   The api saves the data to the harddrive at work and then we read from that file.  The data is fine I just think it is something with express or fetch.

Comment: Have you checked if your request for JSON is not failing?

Comment: it gets the same response.  it fails.  I can't even get the data object.  BUT the exact same data object works fine by itself.   I showed in the example just trying to access the data in the index.ejs file but the first file that works is the same thing same data and it accesses it fine from my hard drive.  It's when it goes through express these errors come up.

Comment: (1)  what is the response (i.e. `console.log(res)`)?  That should provide insight into the error being returned by the server.  (2) Is your express app set up to serve the static resource "2016-regular.json"?  Express will not serve a static file by default, and you are trying to retrieve this static resource with `fetch`.  See [this link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I will check that stuff out now eric.  perhaps if I use sendFile instead but I included how I set up the express app as the last part of code.  I don't believe I specifically said static as I thought what I was doing was the best practice for serving standard files.  I will try what you said. thank you.

Comment: Yes you will need to add a section to your express code to serve static files, as in the link I posted previously.  Otherwise, you will not be able to serve that json file from the server since there is no "route" to it.

Comment: Hey eric I tried what you said read the docs and watched a few youtube videos and had the same problem.  Now my express.js file looks like this   const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000);

console.log('running on port 3000');  I put everything in the public folder even the json and the same exact thing.  Its strange.  I will keep at it.

Comment: See working example in my answer below

Answer (score 5):

I think the bottom line is that you need to make sure your JSON file is reachable/loadable, and then make sure it is valid.  Here is a minimal working example.  You app.js should be simply:

```
var express = require('express');
var index = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();

app.set('views', 'views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/', index);

module.exports = app;
```

Your routes/index.js is simply:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

And your views/index.ejs should be:

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="output">JSON contents will appear here.</div>  
  <button id="getProperty">Click to load JSON</button>

  <script>
      document.getElementById('getProperty').addEventListener('click', getProperty);  
      function getProperty() {
          fetch("./2016-regular.json")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
              document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
          });
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, make sure your JSON file is saved at ./public/2016-regular.json.  Here is mine:

{
    "item1": "value1",
    "item2": "value2",
    "item3": "value3"
}

**TEST 1**  Make sure your JSON file is reachable my pointing your browser to http://localhost:3000/2016-regular.json  (note you may have to change the port if you are running on a different port).

**TEST 2** Navigate to http://localhost:3000/ and click on the button.  The file contents should appear in the results div.

**Full working code** is [available here](https://github.com/erikor/exp1).  Just clone the repository, then

```
cd exp1
npm install
npm start
```

Comment: Man this worked I see I was doing more than a few things wrong.  Which is a bit frustrating I will review and learn.  Thank you very much for your help.  This worked great.

Comment: @baryjones23saturn Great. Keep learning. If this was helpful consider clicking the checkmark and/or upvoting the answer.